# Do I need a comma in "Здравствуйте вновь!"?

Tags: пунктуация

If I write a message to a person second time and want to address him by "Здравствуйте вновь!", do I need to put a comma between those two words?

I have looked through many dictionaries, but no dictionary addresses this particular question.

I have seen many times in Russian writing that there would be a comma right after such words like "привет", "здравствуйте", "добрый день", etc. For example, "Привет, дорогие друзья!"

Comment: Aside from the reasons why this question is closed I can not help but notice that this is just not ho we usually talk. "Здравствуйте вновь"  sounds like a machine translation at best, just go with "И снова здравствуйте"  or "здравствуйте опять".

Comment: @shabunc - Thank you! Tell me, please, do I need a comma between "здравствуйте"and "опять" in "здравствуйте опять"?

Comment: @moderators: re-open my question. No dictionary contains an answer for it.

Comment: Do you put a comma in "hello again"?

Comment: @mustaccio - No, I don't. But what does English punctuation have to do with Russian? In English it's okay not to put comma after "Hello" in "Hello Peter!", while in Russian you would have to.

Comment: The answer to your question would be "you don't, and it's so obvious that no style guide would even mention that". Could you please explain what made you think you needed a comma here? Maybe we're all missing something.

Comment: @Quassnoi - Because I have seen many times in Russian writing that there would be a comma right after such words like "привет", "здравствуйте", "добрый день", etc. For example, "Привет, дорогие друзья!"

Comment: @brilliant mind elaborating on your doubts in the question body, so we could reopen it? Thanks!

Comment: @Quassnoi - I just copied that into my question.

Comment: only if you want to further highlight this "вновь"  - "здраствуйте, вновь !" "Здраствуйте - вновь !"
- but the idiom itself already emphasizes this fact, so I don't know why this is needed:>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have seen many times in Russian writing that there would be a comma right after such words like "привет", "здравствуйте", "добрый день", etc. For example, "Привет, дорогие друзья!"

In this example, the phrase that comes after the greeting is an address (*обращение*).

The addresses are usually isolated by commas in Russian.

Rosenthal et al., 101:

> Обращения вместе со всеми относящимися к ним словами выделяются (в середине предложения) или отделяются (в начале или в конце предложения) запятыми, например: *Дорогие гости, милости просим за стол (Пушкин); Опустись, занавеска линялая, на больные
> герани мои (Блок); Неужели вы его боитесь, Сергей Ильич? (Гранин)*

---

> If I write a message to a person second time and want to address him by "Здравствуйте вновь!", do I need to put a comma between those two words?

In this example *вновь* is not a an address and this rule does not apply.

Comment: What about the comma in a film title like «Здравствуйте, я ваша тётя!»? I am pretty sure that the construction «я ваша тётя» is not an address or vocative, yet we have a comma after the word "здравствуйте".

Comment: @Alexander: _я ваша тетя_ is an independent clause in a compound sentence. There are many reasons you might need to put a comma between words, but none of them apply to the original example. Not needing a comma is the default, it's the opposite you need to justify.

Answer (score -2):

they don't speak Russian like that). we can say - Ещё раз, здравствуйте. or - Здравствуйте, ещё раз)

Comment: welcome to Russian SE. Please, tend not to leave answers that short and that badly formatted - it's just that it (at best) most probably will be downvoted - like in this particular case.